# Changing between CSS Class properties in CSS

Tags: css

In CSS, I was wondering if there was some way how one could use the properties given to an element via a class that would overwrite those given from a  class. For example, it would look something like this:

```
.div_class {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
}

.special_class {
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  color: green;
}
```

And the HTML would look something like this:

```
<div class="div_class">
  <h3>Normal</h3>
  <h3 class="special_class">Special  </h3>
  <h3>Normal</h3>
</div>
```

Apologies if I've made an error in my code, but this is the basic gist.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried !important ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Can element class property overwrite parent's properties?

Comment: Your sample code seems good enough

Comment: @SujanAdiga No, how would one use it?

Comment: you can use `.div_class .special_class {}` to overwrite, please try to avoind `!important` - it can get your code messy

Comment: Yes, !important should be last option

Comment: Is it possible that you can give this in context? Like add it to the code. If it's not too hard.

Comment: You're code is working as expected 
http://codepen.io/sujanadiga/pen/ygqBWv

Answer (score 3):

You've got some mistakes in your code, as unclosed tag `h3` and unclosed css rules, I mean you didn't put a closing braces in the rules. Here is a fixed code

```css
.div_class {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: yellow;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #000;
}
.special_class {
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  color: green;
  text-shadow: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_class">
  <h3>Normal</h3>
  <h3 class="special_class">Special</h3>
  <h3>Normal</h3>
</div>
```